# Adding null bytes to a file using dd

Tags: dd, cloning

I have an img file which I had cloned from a disk of my RISC PC using `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/hdb of=RISCPC.IMG
```

The size around 2GB.

I want to add 512 null bytes to the start and end of the file. What's the best way to do this using `dd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=RISCPC.IMG.new bs=1 count=512
dd if=RISCPC.IMG of=RISCPC.IMG.new bs=512 seek=1
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=512 >> RISCPC.IMG.new
mv RISCPC.IMG{.new,}
```

If you can use `cat`, you might consider this:

```
cat > RISCPC.IMG.new \
    <(dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=1) \
    RISCPC.IMG \
    <(dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=1)
mv RISCPC.IMG{.new,}
```

Comment: dd: unrecognized operand ‘offset=512’

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks, that's a typo. That should be `seek`.

Comment: Doing `dd bs=1` on a whole disk image is going to take hours (1 `read` and 1 `write` system call per byte!).

Comment: I would have done `bs=512 count=1`.

Comment: @bahamat They should both be trivially fast, but true.

Answer (score 3):

512 bytes at the end are added easily enough.

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 >> your.img
```

512 bytes at the start unfortunately require rewriting the entire image.

```
dd if=your.img of=your.img.new seek=1
```

It's very unusual to do this to a HDD image. So I'm wondering if this is what you really wanted.